# JSON Data returned from Ajax on Safari is converted into a javascript list

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, safari

This is something I recently found out, I have the following piece of code in JS:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/requestHandle',
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {
        var places = JSON.parse(data);
        // do something
    },
    error: function(data) {
        // do something else
    }
});
```

The data returned from my backend is indeed in JSON format, and `var places = JSON.parse(data);` this line works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox, it parses my JSON data into a JS list; however, in Safari, `var places = JSON.parse(data);` gives me error, because data is already a JS list. Instead of doing var places = JSON.parse(data), just changing to var places = data solved the error, I am wondering why it is converted automatically?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best solution would be to tell jQuery that the response is json so that you will always receive it as js object

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/requestHandle',
    data: data,
    success: function(obj) {

        // do something
    },
    error: function(data) {
        // do something else
    },
    dataType: 'json'  // reponse is json so it will always be pre-parsed 
});
```